# Group values by keys and calculate their average in a single loop - Python

Tags: python

I have an object (in no particular order)

```
d1 = {'1':['key1',7], '2':['key2',8], '3':['key1',5], '4':['key3',2], '5':['key2',9] ...}
```

I'd like to group the keys & calculate their average:

```
d2 = {'key1':[7,5], 'key2':[8,9], 'key3':[2]... }
```

Here's the code. For pedantic purposes, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in a single loop ? (Not just brute force into a single loop by making it inefficient or unreadable)

```
d2=defaultdict(list)
for v in d1.values():
    d2[v[0]].append(v[1])
for k in d2.keys():
    print float(sum(d2[k]))/len(d2[k])
```

Comment: Do comprehensions and implicit loops work for you?

Comment: Sure, please share the code.

Comment: And where is the average going to be stored?

Comment: Don't need sorting, I've just put the print for demo purpose. Trying to understand how to compute average in a single loop where I'm populating d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby) and `sorted` functions this way:

```
d1 = {'1':['key1',7], '2':['key2',8], '3':['key1',5], '4':['key3',2], '5':['key2',9]}
d2 = sorted(d1.values(), key=lambda l:l[0])
for k,v in itertools.groupby(d2,key=lambda l:l[0]):
    v = list(v)
    print "%s: %s" % (k, sum(l[1] for l in v)/float(len(v)) )

key1: 6.0
key2: 8.5
key3: 2.0
```

`groupby` will associate in this way `key1: [[key1,8], [key1,7]] ...` and what the generator expression does inside the `sum` function is to normlize that list retrieving only the numbers.

This code of course has a lot of implicit loops. But regarding your problem, IMHO it should be hard (if not impossible) to accomplish it with just one loop. I can only think of a set of *finite* keys mapped to an array to access them in O(1) and keep in that data structure the *sum* so far and the *length* so far.

If keys are infinite, you'll have no other option than to iterate (somehow, can be also improved with hashes but still is O(n) worst case)  to find them to update their values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't this a loop `sorted(d1.values(), key=lambda l:l[0])`

Comment: @buffer Yes, internally it is a loop.

Comment: @buffer Since keys aren't ordered accomplishing this stuff in just one loop is impossible I think. If I'm wrong or otherwise my answer doesn't suit your needs please tell me to delete it :)

Comment: @buffer I think this solution is probably optimal (minimizing __user defined__ for loops). I don't think you can avoid `for`s without sorting

Comment: Your answer is another cool way of doing it. However I was wondering if it's really impossible or my understanding is limited.

Comment: Just some thoughts, since keys aren't sorted, when you process one you need to check if it has been visited before. You can do a lot of optimizations, for instance if keys are finite you can map them to an array an access them in O(1) and keep there also the sum of the elements and the length of the list. That probably avoids 2 loops, but if keys are infinite then you need to loop to see if a key is already inserted.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this change to keep the sum & count in the first loop. That should improve it. Thanks.